# Tags for random forests

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment there are two separate tags for questions relating to random forests, [randomforest](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/randomforest) and [random-forest](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-forest). Should these be merged into one? If so, I suggest using [random-forest](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-forest).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have merged the two tags, keeping the older one ([random-forest](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-forest)). Thanks for bringing this to the community attention!